# Draw 50 button dynamically after full activity loaded

Tags: android, performance, android-custom-view

This is on create of my activity and after setting content view , I am calling  LoadButton().

```
        @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

            Loadbuttons();
    }


     public void LoadButtonss()
       {

          Here  I am fetching data from database ,and plotting 50 buttons dynamically
       }
```

So  My Problem is :  **It is taking time in loading activity.**

Any Idea  how to LoadButtons()  after Loading full activity.  It should not wait for the ButtonLoad()  function.

Any Idea how to do that?

Comment: How about a runnable?

Comment: If you fix/change the code to one of the answers, could you fix/change the code in your question as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste this code in your activity class block:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       LoadButtons();
    super.onStart();
}
```

Comment: what if I will put super.onStart(); before LoadButtons();

Comment: super.onStart() run the superclass method first. i think no matter.

Answer (score 0):

According to the activity life cycle, you must call LoadButtons in onStart overrided method. Because activity will be visible in this state.

Comment: Can you please give me some code  sample or edit my answer? I am new in android.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this: Load buttons in onCreate and set View invisible. in onResume make it visible again.

```
View v;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    v= findViewById(R.layout.main);
    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Loadbuttons();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    super.onResume();
}


 public void LoadButtons()
   {
         FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.MarkerLinearlayout); 
      //Here  I am fetching data from database ,and plotting 50 buttons dynamically
   }
```

Comment: Then make you layout membervariable and switch from invisible to visible. Layouts are Views too ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the buttons to invisible and if you fetch the data you can update the UI through an AsyncThread. It is not the nicest way, but it works. Otherwise use instead of Buttons a CustomListView.